# Issue on config.xml passing in cordova 5.2

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I need to update my apk in playstore. So i changed my version in config.xml as usual. But now it throw errorrs in parsing config.xml.

Also i tried new project and build it. it worked fine for me. But When i change version of new project same errors thrown.

CLI

```
myapp$ cordova build android

Parsing /Users/abid/Android/phonegap/myapp/config.xml failed

Error: Unquoted attribute value

Line: 1

Column: 41

Char: “

    at error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:347:8)

    at strictFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:364:22)

    at Object.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:913:11)

    at XMLParser.feed (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)

    at ElementTree.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:271:10)

    at Object.exports.XML (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:606:13)

    at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/util/xml-helpers.js:123:38)

    at Object.ConfigParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/configparser/ConfigParser.js:33:24)

    at getScriptsFromConfigXml (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:108:21)

    at getApplicationHookScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/scriptsFinder.js:56:17)
```

Config.xml

````
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<widget id="com.demo.myapp" version=“1.3.1” xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

    <name>myapp</name>

    <description>

        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.

    </description>

    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">

        Apache Cordova Team

    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version=“3” />

    <access origin="*" />

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />

    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />

    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />

    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />

    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">

        <allow-intent href="market:*" />

    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">

        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />

        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />

    </platform>


</widget>
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character **“** is not the same as **"**. Use a real text editor such as notepad, vim to correct the quotes around the version number.